# Probability - Roulette

Tags: probability, expectation

A gambling book recommends the following strategy for the game
of roulette. It recommends that a gambler bets 1 euro on red. If red appears (with
probability 18
38 ), then the gambler should take his or her profit and quit the game.
If the gambler loses his or her bet (which has probability 20
38 of occurring), he
should make additional 1 euro bets on red on each of the next two spins of the
roulette wheel and then quit. Let X denote the gambler’s winnings when he quits.
(a) Find P(X >0).
(b) Is this a winning strategy? Explain your answer.
(c) Compute E(X).

Comment: He is wagering Euros on an American wheel?  very strange.

Comment: from a book written by European author who loved venturing in Vegas I guess :)

Comment: You're not very likely to get answers here unless you show some effort in solving the problem and can tell us at least roughly what confuses you or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenarios:
1) he wins the first bet.  Net + 1

2) he loses the first bet and wins bets 2 and 3.  Net + 1

3) he loses the first bet and splits bets 2 and 3. Net -1

4) he loses all 3.  Net -3

$P(1) = \frac {18}{38}\\
P(2) = \frac {20}{38}(\frac {18}{38})^2\\
P(3) = \frac {20}{38}(2\cdot \frac {18}{38}\frac {20}{38})\\
P(4) = (\frac {20}{38})^3$

If I set it up correctly we have covered all of the possibilities, and $P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) = 1$

$P(X>0) = P(1) + P(2)$

b) Roulette has a house edge on every bet placed of $\frac {2}{38}.$ This edge does not go away under any betting strategy.

c) $E(X) = P(1) + P(2) - P(3) - 3P(4)$